# How to get the entire block blob for submission after mining a nonce?

Tags: monerod, mining, daemon, rpc, api

After mining a correct nonce on the block template (received from rpc method "**getblocktemplate**") you need to submit the block back to the daemon. However, the rpc method "**submitblock**" appears to require the *entire* block blob. The template does not contain the entire block, just the parts necessary for mining. And I don't see any way to derive the full block information from the template to create the block blob.

So how do I mine on the template and then submit the full block back to the daemon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getbklocktemplate` RPC returns a `blockhashing_blob` and a `blocktemplate_blob`.

You can either try to find a nonce (4 bytes) by mining using the `blockhashing_blob`, or you can try to find two nonces (4 bytes in the block header, `reserved_size` bytes in the *extra* field of the mining reward transaction) using the `blocktemplate_blob` and computing the transaction Merkle tree yourself.

When your nonce(s) pass the difficulty test, you put it/them in the `blocktemplate_blob` at the right offset(s) and you send the updated `blocktemplate_blob` to the daemon using the `submitblock` RPC.

Comment: I checked the source code for monerod, the submit block code calls **cryptonote_format_utils.parse_and_validate_block_from_blob**. I dont think that method can handle parsing a template/hashing blob? It appears that it wants a block header or full block blob?

Comment: The ```blocktemplate_blob``` is a block header.

Comment: Block headers do not contain a tree root hash (per the source code at least), and the tree root hash is part of the hashing blob.  
Edit: The tree hash is tacked onto the end. So when the code parses the blob, its going to attempt to parse an entire block, and then run into the tree hash, right?

Comment: The ```blockhashing_blob``` contains the transaction tree hash root (because it's a preprocessed block header), but the ```blocktemplate_blob``` doesn't (because it is a raw block header). When you submit the ```blocktemplate_blob``` updated with your nonce, the daemon processes it, check if it is valid and sends it to the network if it is.

Comment: Ah okay, so there is some of my confusion. When you say "raw block header" you're actually talking about the _entire block_ (in source code terms), because the block header (in source terms) is a small part of the block comprised of only major, minor, time, prev, nonce. The value of the template is actually an entire block struct, and so it parses correctly.