# Does core_rpc_server::on_submitblock need full block blob?

Tags: monerod, daemon, rpc, source, api

It looks like the core_rpc_server::on_submitblock method is expecting a full block blob, since it calls...

```
 if(!parse_and_validate_block_from_blob(blockblob, b))
```

However this RPC method is used to submit blocks that are mined on just the hashing blob. So how does the method work correctly when just the hashing blob is passed in, if it's trying to parse a full block blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of answered indirectly here:

[How to get the entire block blob for submission after mining nonce](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/how-to-get-the-entire-block-blob-for-submission-after-mining-nonce)

That method requires a block header. The "hashing_blob" is not the correct input, its the block_template that should be used.