# Using a block template to mine

Tags: monerod, mining

I am a little confused about how I use the block template. I saw [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/what-is-the-format-of-a-block-in-the-monero-blockchain) which leads me to think that perhaps I need to call [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/960886aa04f0b50265884c0d4338031a93b1bc5d/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L883) function until I get a hash that fits the difficulty. Basically what are the function calls I need to perform in order to mine a block template so I can then call submit block.

Sorry if this is a vague question I am just quite confused.

I have also seen [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/how-to-get-the-entire-block-blob-for-submission-after-mining-nonce) question but again it doesn't really answer what function I should call.

Just for more context I am calling monero from a bazel repository so things are a bit hairy and complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am a little confused about how I use the block template... Basically what are the function calls I need to perform in order to mine a block template so I can then call submit block.

A block template is just that, a template for a block that a miner can perform work on (repeated hashing) to try and find a solution (a hash that meets the network difficulty) and then submit to the network.

So first a miner obtains a block template, typically using the daemon method [get_block_template](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_template).

Next the miner relatedly updates the nonce space<sup>1</sup> and performs a hash<sup>2</sup> (using the RandomX hash function). If / when the resulting hash (which is just a number) meets the network difficulty, they can submit the block to the network using the daemon method [submit_block](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#submit_block).

Lastly, peer nodes validate that any proposed blocks hash meets the network difficulty. If no other miner submits a valid block (or chain of blocks) with more work done, after 60 blocks the miner gets paid the reward.

<sub>1</sub> the nonce space can be any combination of the nonce field in the block header or in any reserved space of the miner transaction.

<sub>2</sub> what actually gets hashed is a block hashing blob, which is a concatenation of the block header, a merkle root hash of the blocks transactions and a varint of the count of txs ([src](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/960886aa04f0b50265884c0d4338031a93b1bc5d/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L820)). A miner can either directly use the returned block hashing blob from `get_block_template` or they can construct the block hashing blob themselves using the block template blob. The latter is required if the miner is changing the reserved space of the miner tx.